# How to access noticeOperations from withNotices

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, block-editor

In my edit.js file I want to access noticeOperations which I thought I could do via props but if I console.log props it isn't there.

```
import {
    withNotices,
} from "@wordpress/components";

export function Edit(props) {
   console.log(props);
   // code
}

export default withNotices(Edit);
```

Comment: You're exporting 2 components here. You're exporting `Edit`, which is not using notices, and then you're exporting a version with notices as the `default`. If you `import { Edit } from` that's the component without notices. You would need to `import Edit from` to use the default export, which uses notices.

Comment: what are you trying to do that requires this? What's the context? This isn't something block edit components would normally do, anything you can tell us about the why and how of this will help enormously in detailing how to correctly work with this. Also what is your `// code` section? I notice there is no information about how block props are being added

Comment: @JacobPeattie, aahhhh. I see what I was doing wrong now. I changed it to `const Edit = (props) =>  {` and then `export default withNotices(Edit);`. That seems to have done the trick. Thanks!